# Dockerize node app with dependency restriction

Tags: windows, docker, darwin

Ok so I wrote a nodejs webapp, and after finishing and wanting to send it to production, I dockerized it. After creating the image and running the container, it will die wirh this error:

```
linux is NOT supported
```

So given that, I looked up on my node_modules (dependencies) folder, and found this on one of my critcal dependencies:

```
if (!['darwin', 'win32'].includes(platform)) {
    console.error(`${platform} is NOT supported.`);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

So my question is: Is there any way I can make this work on a docker container?
Thanks